# Split a string of characters containing alphabets and digits and extract the characters as string items in a list

Tags: python-re

I have following 6 string cases:

text1 = 'Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 9am-12pm; Sa,Su 9am-12pm Closed'

text2 = 'Mo,Tu,We,Th 7am-11pm; Fr,Sa,Su 12pm-11pm Closed'

text3 = 'Mo,Tu,We 10am-10pm; Th,Fr,Sa,Su 10am-8pm Closed'

text4 = 'Mo,Tu 9am-10pm; Wd,Th,Fr,Sa,Su 1pm-8pm Closed'

text5 = 'Mo 9am-11pm; Tu,Wd,Th,Fr,Sa,Su 7am-11pm Closed'

using re or regex module in python I want to extract the following in list

1. From text1 I want to extract
   ['MoTuWeThFr','9am','12pm'] and
   ['SaSu', '9am','10pm']
2. From text2 I want to extract
   ['MoTuWe','7am','11pm'] and
   ['FrSaSu', '12pm','11pm']
3. From text3 I want to extract
   ['MoTuWe','10am','10pm'] and
   ['ThFrSaSu', '10am','8pm']
4. From text4 I want to extract
   ['MoTu','9am','10pm'] and
   ['WdThFrSaSu', '1pm','8pm']
5. From text4 I want to extract
   ['Mo','9am','11pm'] and
   ['TuWdThFrSaSu', '7am','11pm']

Can somebody provide the regex expressions for all the above 5 cases ??

Can somebody provide me the regex expressions for all the above 5 cases so that I can learn more about regex its confusing me ??